# EditText suggestion bar flickers when focus go to listview and back to edit text

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-edittext

I have chat list view and send message edit text below it. When message got sent, i add it to listView and then refresh the adapter. Unfortunately whenI did that, the list does not scroll up even after I set listView.setSelected(adapter.getcount()). After investigating this I found that listview does not get focus. so I set the focus first by `lstMessages.requestFocus();` then `lstMessages.setSelection(adapter.getCount());`, then get the focus back to the edittext. the problem now is that the suggestion bar above the edittext disappears when focus lost and appear when focus gets back causing flickering and very bad ux. Any solution or suggestion for the full issue ?

Please don't tell me to hide the suggestion bar, I don't want to disable this feature for users plus it does not work in all devices.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you try `lstMessages.smoothScrollToPosition` instead of `requestFocus` ??

Comment: I tried that now. It worked, Thanks a lot. You may make it as answer to accept it ;)

Comment: @Panther , it did not work man sorry. Don't know sometime it works sometime not. trying to figure out the reason

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should try to post to the `ListView` like this. Try to call `smoothScrollToPosition`. If that does not works, try `setSelection`

```
lstMessages.post( new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
    lstMessages.smoothScrollToPosition(position) ;
    }
  });
```